# Can we configure HangFire to schedule a job per user at different time intervals?

Tags: .net-core, scheduler, job-scheduling, hangfire

We want to give feasibility for the user from UI to schedule a job from 15 minutes to 23:59 hours of the time range. By which different users may select different time slots to run their jobs.

For example: 
Scenario-1: User A wants to schedule the job to run every 15 minutes.
Scenario-2: User B wants to schedule the job to run every 30 minutes.
So on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post my answer for my own question.
I used Recurring job with a *Unique identifier* (i.e., $"userid_{job.UserId}" ) which is the first parameter in **Recurring.AddOrUpdate()** method by which separate recurring jobs will be created for each user. Please have a look at the below code to understand.
Now Hangfire will create 4 recurring jobs for 4 different users with different frequencies.

```
            List<Scheduler> list = new List<Scheduler>
            {               
                new Scheduler { EveryXMinutes = 3, UserId = 1023028, On = true },
                new Scheduler { EveryXMinutes = 5, UserId = 1023023, On = true },
                new Scheduler { EveryXMinutes = 10, UserId = 1023025, On = true },
                new Scheduler { EveryXMinutes = 15, UserId = 1023027, On = true }
            };
            foreach (var job in list)
            {
                if (job.On)
                {
                    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate($"userid_{job.UserId}", () => demoService.RunTaskDemo2(job.UserId), $"*/{job.EveryXMinutes} * * * *");
                }
                else
                {
                    RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists($"userid_{job.UserId}");
                }
            }
```

**RunTaskDemo2(int)** is a common method which runs for every user

```
        public void RunTaskDemo2(int userid)
        {
            // Any code of your own
            Console.WriteLine("--------------&&&&&----------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"RUNNING TASK FOR USERID {userid} - {i.ToString()}");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------^^^^^^^----------------------");
        }
```

I hope this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a recurring job, you could format the job uid as "Do Stuff ()". For each user use AddOrUpdate() to register the task with their own cron schedules.